# matrix in one column in two column paper

Tags: matrices

How can i put a matrix in one column in two column paper? I want this type of output:[image: er]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ, how wide the columns are, which font and which font size are in use, and whether you use the `amsmath` package to typeset equations and matrices.

Comment: \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
%\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

%\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
\hyphenpenalty=8000
%\textwidth=128mm
%\textheight=244mm
%\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 9.6in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfigure}

Comment: i have used above all these.

Comment: Please edit the crucial information about document class and packages directly into the question. It is too easy to miss and too hard to read in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would *not* let the matrix be wider than `\columnwidth`, the more so since the four complicated-looking cells can be simplified considerably by factoring out common elements, as is demonstrated in the following.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' environment
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\addtocounter{enumi}{2} % just for this example
\item In order to study the local stability behavior
of positive equilibrium, let $J\vert_{E^*}$ be the
variational matrix evaluated at $E^*(x^*,y^*,z^*)$.
\[
J\vert_{E^*}=
\begin{bmatrix} 
  -ry^*\!/x 
     & r 
     & -\rho x^* \\
  r  & -sy^*\!/K-rx^*\!/y^* +a\psi 
     & -y^*\varphi \\
  c_1\rho z^*
     & c_2 z^*\varphi 
     & -\delta_1 z^* -c_2c\psi
\end{bmatrix}
\]
where $\varphi\equiv\alpha/[(1+ay^*)^2(1+bz^*)]$ and 
$\psi\equiv y^*z^*\varphi$.
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[1] % filler text

\end{document}
```